# How to retrieve the display property of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        a {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <p id="p"> a paragraph </p>
        <a href="http://www.google.com" id="a">google</a>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = (document.getElementById('a')).style;
        alert(a.display);
        var p = (document.getElementById('p')).style;
        alert(p.display);
        p.display = 'none';
        alert(p.display);
    </script>
</html>
```

The first and the second `alert` display nothing other than a empty string, which I thought should be `none` and `block`.
However after the intensionally `display` setting, the third `alert` finally alert `none`.

But Why? How could I retrieve the `display` property correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `.style.*` properties map directly onto the `style` **attribute**, not to the applied style. For that you want [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

I'd give serious consideration to toggling `.className` and separating the presentation from the logic entirely.

Comment: style should not be called an attribute. It is an object. Each DOM element node has a style property. This property is an object. ... The HTML style attribute is used to add properties to the style property of the DOM node that represents the HTML element. Once the HTML code is parsed, we do not have HTML attributes anymore, but object properties.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I think if you re-read David's answer, you'll realize he's drawn that distinction correctly.

Comment: @David Dorward: Thanks for your help. So what's the usage of `style` attribute since it could not mirror the real-time change of the CSS style?

Comment: @jcyang: The `style` object on the element in the DOM is for changing the style applied to that *specific element*, just like the `style` attribute in markup. If you want to modify the style definition in the stylesheet, you can do that, it's just elsewhere: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Stylesheet

Comment: The style attribute exists before HTML parsing. Once the page is parsed, there is no style attribute anymore. The style object may be manipulated upon and then it will no longer "map" to the original style attribute of the HTML source code.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: *"Once the HTML code is parsed, we do not have HTML attributes anymore, but object properties."* Actually, the attributes become DOM attributes -- specifically, [attribute nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1841493061). The correct terminology is that these properties on the `style` object *reflect* the "style" attribute (just as `className` reflects the "class" attribute).

Comment: Those attribute nodes are properties, not attributes. In the object model of the browser there exist only properties. These properties can be objects or primitive values. Each DOM node (regardless of type) is a property. The HTML style attribute is used to set up the initial style object of the DOM element. (btw, in JavaScript terminology, attributes are a completely different thing - they are meta-information bound to each property. These attributes define if the property is for example read-only)

Comment: @David Dorward: So `style` attribute/object is only for changing and the computed style/currentStyle is for viewing?

Comment: Changes done to the style property are of course viewable, too.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: Thanks. It is true that the changes are viewable. I have tested it.

Comment: [`classList.toggle`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) should be used in modern code, instead of `className`.

Answer (score 8):

You need the computed value of the display property for the element. You can get this as follows. Note that most browsers support [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3awindow.getComputedStyle) whereas the nearest equivalent in IE is the element's `currentStyle` property:

```
var el = document.getElementById('a');
var styleObj;

if (typeof window.getComputedStyle != "undefined") {
    styleObj = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
} else if (el.currentStyle != "undefined") {
    styleObj = el.currentStyle;
}

if (styleObj) {
   alert(styleObj.display);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using a JavaScript library for getting computed style. For example, using jQuery you can retrieve computed style with the css() method...

```
$("#a").css("display");
```

The css() method is a cross-browser solution as it internally uses the style object and both the getComputedStyle method and the currentStyle object.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, there is a method called `.is`

To check if something isn't displayed, I'd do ... `$('someSelector').is(':visible')` ...

This would return false if display attribute is set to None.