# I set the display property of an HTML element in CSS. But, if I check that value in javascript it shows blank

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my separate CSS file I set the display property of a div to "none".

HTML file:

```
<div class="ttt"><span id="debugInfo">Load Time, Render Time, Latency, TCP Handshake time, etc ...</span></div>
```

CSS file:

```
.ttt {
       display: none;
       background-color: rgb(184, 88, 88);
}
```

The div is changing its background to the specified color and the div disappears like it's suppose to.

But, if I check the property in Javascript, it's blank.  I get elements like this many other places.  I check it and I get the right div.  Just that if I check style.display I get blank.

Javascript file:

```
function changeVisibilty(pID, pInline) {
  var el = document.getElementById(pID);

  console.log(el.style.display); return;

  //   console.log(el); return;
}
```

NOW if I get rid of the CSS display: none and put it inline in the HTML it works.

```
div class="ttt" style="display: none"><span id="debugInfo">Load Time, Render Time, Latency, TCP Handshake time, etc ...</span></div>
```

Like I said before, the CSS is working. Cause, it sets the background color and makes the div disappear.  HTML and CSS have been ran thru Validators. I dont want to use any other methods.  Like setting hidden to false, changing opacity, moving it off-screen, etc ...

I need the style stuff to stay in the CSS file and I want to use display: none.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the display property of a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778335/how-to-retrieve-the-display-property-of-a-dom-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
el.style.display
```

Use

```
getComputedStyle(el).display
```

[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `window.getComputedStyle()` to get the CSS set for an element. `.style` checks the `style` attribute values within HTML.

Note also, `.getElementById()` gets an element by `id`, you can use `.querySelector()` to select element having `class` set to `"ttt"`.

```
function changeVisibilty(pID, pInline) {
  var el = document.querySelector(pID);
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(el).display);
}

onload = () => changeVisibilty(".ttt")

.ttt {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgb(184, 88, 88);
}

<div class="ttt"><span id="debugInfo">Load Time, Render Time, Latency, TCP Handshake time, etc ...</span></div>
```