# Changing HTML button text color multiple times with JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to write a function that will change a button's text color to red on the first click, green on the second click and back to black on the third click (and so forth). My idea is that this should be fairly straightforward to accomplish with an `if else` statement that checks a button's color and then changes it. I've gotten the color to change on the first click just fine but I don't seem to be able to get any kind of result on the next clicks. So far I have a series of buttons that contain `onclick = "changeColor(this)` and call:

```js
function changeColor(alphaButton) {
  if (alphaButton.style.color == "black") {
    alphaButton.style.color = "red";
  } else if (alphaButton.style.color == "red") {
    alphaButton.style.color = "green";
  } else if (alphaButton.style.color == "green") {
    alphaButton.style.color = "black";
  }
}
```

The `if` statement works fine but I'm not sure why it's not working past that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[UPDATE]

Ok, figured this one out. It appears I hadn't properly set my text color (although I thought I had it properly set inline). Now everything functions perfectly. Still, I would have assumed that black text would automatically read as black text without being specified as such. Definitely a frustrating and time consuming way to learn that this isn't the case.

Comment: `=` is assignment ... you want `==` in the test

Comment: May be of interest: [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Comment: That totally makes sense, but replacing = with == breaks even the first click. I guess the check I thought I was making isn't happening at all and I was just assigning the button to black? Not exactly sure what's going on here...

Comment: Is the button's 1st color set in the element's `style` attribute or through a stylesheet? – Possibly related: [How to retrieve the display property of a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778335/how-to-retrieve-the-display-property-of-a-dom-element)

Comment: It's inline on the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommended in general not to rely on reading back style properties. Besides the fact that the button's initial `style.color` will be blank unless set manually, the color could've been set to `#000`, which has the same effect but will break your code.

Here's how I'd do this:

```js
const colors = ["black", "red", "orange", "green", "blue"];

function changeColor(button) {
  var current = Number(button.dataset.ci || 0); // init to 0 on first click
  current = (current + 1) % colors.length; // clamp array index
  button.dataset.ci = current; // store new value in element
  button.style.color = colors[current]; // set color
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeColor(this)">Click</button>
```

Comment: Definitely a much better solution, thanks for your help!

Comment: Damn it, beat me to it. I'd just add some code comments to expand on what you're doing for those not familiar with data attributes, your use of || to switch on null and you use of the modulo operator to keep in bounds (which I'd never seen before)

Comment: There's no reason this would only work for three colors, right? When I add more colors it breaks it, I guess I'm missing something here since I can't understand why that would be the case.

Comment: @ItaiYasur Apparently all dataset members are strings, fixed the code.

Answer (score 2):

In the `if` `else` conditions, you need to compare color style and the color string with `===` operator instead. You're using `=`, which is an assignment operator.

Comment: That's a complete 3 in the morning mistake from me. Still, this doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing the check I thought I was making isn't actually working.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning variables in your if statement. Change to:

```
function changeColor(alphaButton) {
    if (alphaButton.style.color == "black") {
        alphaButton.style.color = "red"; 
    } else if (alphaButton.style.color == "red") {
        alphaButton.style.color = "green"; 
    } else if (alphaButton.style.color == "green") {
        alphaButton.style.color = "black"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a complete 3 in the morning mistake from me. Still, this doesn't seem to work. I'm guessing the check I thought I was making isn't actually working.