# JS/CSS: backgroundColor for second class

Tags: javascript, css

I am grabbing the element below like:

```
let box = document.querySelector('.zero');
```

When I go to check the backgroundColor in javascript, it shows as `""` :

```
 box.style.backgroundColor    // ""
```

If I'm grabbing the element node, why doesn't it list the backgroundColor as `#DCDCDC`, like what I set it in my CSS as?  I assume it's due to the multiple classes on the element but not sure why.

code:

```
<div class="tic-tac-box zero">
</div>


.tic-tac-box {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Most likely need to use `getcomputedstyle` instead. Since javascript is looking for the inline style and not the applied css.

Comment: Like @imvain2 says you will want `getcomputedstyle`,  the `element.style`, is what your putting inside `<Element style="?"/>` or what you might have set using `setAttribute('style`,'')` etc.

Comment: window.getComputedStyle(box).backgroundColor will do it

Comment: getComputedStyle gives the rgb colour for the hex value, might not be the intended result?

Comment: I deleted my answer, there's a better answer here for how to get the CSS values instead of the computed values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46828223/get-css-not-computed-property-value-with-javascript-only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve the display property of a DOM element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778335/how-to-retrieve-the-display-property-of-a-dom-element)

Comment: It works with getComputedStyle.  Thanks.  I didn’t realize style.backgroundColor only grabbed the inline styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not logging the color is *not* because there are multiple classes, but because how the DOM API works, and that Javascript doesn't know what's going on with your linked CSS. If you want to log the current style of your element you'll have to use the [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method:

```
getComputedStyle(box).backgroundColor); // rgb(220, 220, 220)
```

**tldr**: "The style property only retrieves inlined CSS values while getComputedStyle style retrieves computed CSS values." [Check out this article for more info.](https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js/) You'll notice when you set colors with that syntax, it appends inline styles too.